# Passing switch to argumentlist of scheduled job

Tags: powershell, arguments, job-scheduling

I am trying to pass a switch argument in a scheduled job. However, no matter what I try, the switch isn't passed. This is a sample script to be called by the scheduled job:

```
Param([switch]$Log = $false)

if($Log)
{
    Write-Host "It is on: $Log"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "It is off: $Log"
}
```

These are the things I tried to pass the switch when creating the job:

```
Register-ScheduledJob -FilePath "C:\Users\foo\Documents\Test.ps1" -Name "Test" -ArgumentList "-Log"
Register-ScheduledJob -FilePath "C:\Users\foo\Documents\Test.ps1" -Name "Test" -ArgumentList ("-Log")
Register-ScheduledJob -FilePath "C:\Users\foo\Documents\Test.ps1" -Name "Test" -ArgumentList (,"-Log")
Register-ScheduledJob -FilePath "C:\Users\foo\Documents\Test.ps1" -Name "Test" -ArgumentList @("-Log")
Register-ScheduledJob -FilePath "C:\Users\foo\Documents\Test.ps1" -Name "Test" -ArgumentList @(,"-Log")
Register-ScheduledJob -FilePath "C:\Users\foo\Documents\Test.ps1" -Name "Test" -ArgumentList @("-Log:$true")
Register-ScheduledJob -FilePath "C:\Users\foo\Documents\Test.ps1" -Name "Test" -ArgumentList @($true)
```

... and many others

I then test the job by getting the job and run it:

```
$job = Get-ScheduledJob -Name Test
$job.run()
```

However, the switch is always false. The `-ArgumentList` parameter takes an array of object (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psscheduledjob/register-scheduledjob?view=powershell-5.1). But I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Comment: `$job.run()` -> `$job.StartJob()`

Comment: Your first attempt (`-ArgumentList "-Log"`) is correct and should work.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks for the info. I now use `$job.StartJob` with `-ArgumentList "-Log"` but, unfortunately I get `"Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter"` error. I'll keep trying with alternatives

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

after searching a while and doing some trial and error approach I found this to work:

`Register-ScheduledJob -FilePath "C:\Users\foo\Documents\Test.ps1" -Name "Test" -ArgumentList @($True)`

Apparantly, $true & $True are not the same...

Thanks for pointing me to the right directions